# Tables not joining properly SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, heidisql

I have two tables like so

```
Table A: Filename: (12345678_123456) Age: (100)

Table B: Filename: (12345678_123456) ID: (501)
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT B.Filename, A.Age, B.ID FROM DB.A INNER JOIN B ON B.Filename WHERE B.ID >=0 AND B.ID <=100 LIMIT 100;
```

There are two problems. The first is that when it gets to an ID of 6,240 the ID and Filename wrap back around and then repeats the same ID and filenames for another iteration of 6,240 ID's. The second problem is that each iteration of 6,240 ID's, the age is staying exactly the same. I'm a beginner at SQL and this is getting me rather frustrated. If anyone could point out my (probably obvious) mistake(s), it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS? You can't be using all 3 at once

Comment: All 3? I'm using HeidiSQL which uses MySQL. I removed the tag of sql-server-2008.

Comment: It was tagged with SQL Server 2008 before. It's removed now, so moot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT B.Filename, A.Age, B.ID
FROM DB.A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON B.Filename
WHERE B.ID >=0 AND B.ID <=100
LIMIT 100;
```

It doesn't make sense, especially the `on` clause.  I might guess that you mean:

```
SELECT B.Filename, A.Age, B.ID
FROM DB.A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON B.Filename = A.FileName
WHERE B.ID >=0 AND B.ID <=100
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your id is always between 0 and 100 according to your condition clause
B.ID >=0 AND B.ID <=100, you shouldn't be able to get anything as large as 6,240

Comment: I was just using that for some testing and didn't change it in my question, I obviously set it to higher than 100 when I was getting that problem.